# qt project code to xml file transformation

Tags: java, c++, xml, qt

i want to convert some qt project files to xml with c++ or java 
for exemple the code do this transformation :

```
 TextInput {
    id: textInput2
    x: 247
    y: 161
    width: 80
    height: 20

}
```

to have  :

```
< TextInput >
    < id> textInput2< /id> 
    < x> 247< /x>
    < y> 161< /y> 
    < width> 80< /width>
    < height> 20 < /height>
< /TextInput >
```

do you have some ideas to do this ? what  technology i have to apply to transform qt to xml ?

edit : i tried SAX XML PARSER but the code don't know how to read .

thanks

Comment: If you want convert qml code to xml, pickup qqml lexer/parser and create visitor

Comment: do you have a link to start up ?

Comment: [sources of QQmlJsAstVisitor](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtdeclarative/source/5a9f0131f8c0b7424a4d323b0f65237206be45ea:src/qml/parser/qqmljsastvisitor_p.h)
[visitor usage example in QtCreator](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/source/dfae73650553d86eb3477be36a32989a0fed89ad:tests/auto/qml/codemodel/check/tst_check.cpp#L130)

Comment: thanks @nib but how can i use it ?

Comment: To used it you will need a qmljs library sources. Then you will pass sources to lexer and later you will go to writing own Visitor/Evaluator/etc.

Comment: thanks again @nib ! do you have some tutorial ? or website? i m just beginner

Comment: Sorry, I dont think that there are any docs, this is internal Api in Qt:(

Answer (score 0):

Surely there's already a lib which makes it possible, but I don't know it, so, if you want to do it by code, you can try to read it as plain text and do translation manually using BufferedReader and a few loops.

Try this:

```
 BufferedReader qtIn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("example.qt")); //I don't know if you can read it as plain text straight.
String tag
String metaTag
String lineIn
String lineOut
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("example.xml"));

//here you should use writer to write down the heading of the xml file.

 while ((lineIn = qtIn.readLine()) != null) {                      // while loop begins here. lineIn is the string where reader stores current line read.
    if (lineIn.charAt(lineIn.length() - 1) == "{"){                //if line's last character is an opening brace ({)
        metaTag = lineIn.subString(0, lineIn.length() - 1).trim(); //we store it in string metaTag
        lineOut = "<"+metaTag+">\n";                               //and write metaTag as opening XML tag
        writer.write (lineOut,0,lineOut.length());
    }else if (lineIn.trim() == "}"){                               //else, if it's a closing brace (})
        lineOut = "</"+metaTag+">\n";                              //we write metaTag as closing XML tag
        writer.write (lineOut,0,lineOut.length());
    }else{                                                         // if it's not an opening or closing brace
        String[] element = lineIn.split(":");                      //we split the line in element name and element data using the colon as splitter. don't forget to use trim method on both parts.
        tag = element[0].trim();                                   //this is optional, you can replace it by using element[0].trim() instead in the next line, I added it just to make it clearer
        lineOut = "<" + tag + ">" + element[1].trim() + "</" + tag +">\n"  // here, we take two element parts and write them as XML tag and plain text.
         writer.write (lineOut,0,lineOut.length());
    }
   }                                                                  // end while 

//here you should write the footing of the file, if there's any.
writer.close();                                                       // don't forget to close writer
```

I think I'm not missing anything. Don't forget to close your file. Also, I'm parting from the concept that the structure of the qt & xml file may vary and it has not complex child nodes. If you know beforehand the structure of the qt file it's a lot easier, and you may use DOM parser to write XML.

Comment: i didnt understand **thisLine**  variable

Comment: Sorry, I copied this code from scraps of my programs, and due to the hurry  I didn't change it. I'm editing now.

Comment: Here, I also added some comments for help, Hope it helps you